# How I can add lenses stacked on front of iphone camera to increase magnifying power?

Tags: optics, visible-light, lenses, optical-materials, camera

How we can stack different lenses to increase magnifiying power of a smartphone camera? Is there any way to test if stacked lenses will focus light on image sensor of smartphone exactly right before attach it in front of camera lens? Noob question. I need to understand basics. Any help welcomed

Comment: By [purchasing one](https://www.google.com/search?q=iphone+zoom+lens)?

Comment: [Some suggestions?](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/guest-blogs/2019/adapting-an-iphone-for-astrophotography.html)

Comment: The optical path of any camera performs the same function as the optical path of a human eye:  It projects a real-image of the scene in front of it onto a receptor/sensor. Therefore, if you hold your camera's lens close to the eyepiece of any optical devices that was meant for a human to peer into (telescope, microscope, magnifying glass, etc.), your camera should see pretty much the same thing that your eye would see. But don't take my word for it. Try it!

Comment: P.S., You can buy various different kinds of accessory lens that are designed to clip on, slip on, or otherwise mount to a cell phone camera. Often they are described as "adaptors" (e.g., "telephoto adapter", "wide-angle adapter", "macro adapter.") Sounds like you want a macro adapter/macro accessory lens. (That's the photographer's name for what the rest of us call a magnifying glass.)